# How do you open a browser to a URL using ActivePerl on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl, browser

In ActivePerl on Windows, how do I open a browser to some URL?

In Python, there is `webbrowser.open(url)`, but I can't seem to find the Perl equivalent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if there's a "right" way to do it, but this should work:

```
my @command = ('start', $url);
system(@command);
```

"start" is a windows command that will use whatever the associated program is to open the argument. So as long as $url looks like a URL (make sure it starts with http(s)://), it should start up the browser.

Comment: Side note: some frameworks, like wxPerl, include functions to do this for you in a platform independent way. See http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_miscellany.html#wxlaunchdefaultbrowser

Answer (score 1):

I know you're using ActivePerl on Windows, but if you want portability then a `system()` call is probably the wrong way to go. On OS X, you could change `'start'` to `'open'`, but on many other systems you'll have to use another word, or may not have an equivalent command at all. This kind of thing is really OS- and browser-dependent.

Comment: Well, the version that is going to run on windows will be using a system tray icon and Activestate's PDK, so that part would need a rewrite for unixes anyway.

Answer (score -1):

on windows: start
on modern unixen (that is to say, those with xdg-utils installed):
xdg-open